# Missing Class in JAR file java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: or g/eclipse/core/runtime/spi/IRegistryProvider

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, birt, eclipse-classpath

I'm trying to integrate my gwt webapp with Birt.

Currently I am using an RPC connection to make a request from the client side to the server side which will run the [SimpleCreate.java](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java_-_Simple_Design_Engine_API_(BIRT)) Eclipse tutorial.

However, when I run the app I get a:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: or g/eclipse/core/runtime/spi/IRegistryProvider
```

I encountered a similar problem before when it was looking for `CoreException` and from this [post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/263330/) it was a classpath error and was solved by adding a different jar file.

Unfortunately, I can't find an answer on the web even though there were questions similar to mine. Is this a classpath error and I'm missing a jar file or something else?
Currently, I am using birt runtime 4.6.0 and gwt 2.8.1.

Comment: IRegistryProvider is in the org.eclipse.equinox.registry plugin jar

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of the error, can I ask how you were able to find it?

Comment: I just used the Eclipse 'Open Type' dialog to open IRegistryProvider and then did a 'Show In > Package Explorer' to see which Eclipse plugin it was in.

Comment: Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @greg-449, You can put the same on an answer so that Winston can accept it as a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IRegistryProvider` is in the `org.eclipse.equinox.registry` plugin jar

You can find out the plugin containing a class by using 'Navigate > Open Type...' to open the class and then in the editor context menu using 'Show In > Package Explorer' to see the package.

To get 'Open Type' to include the Eclipse code you need to check the 'Include all plug-ins from target in Java search' option on the 'Plug-in Development' Preferences page.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449